# set up oauth2.0 key for google api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am trying to run the sample application of [DrEdit](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python) given in the Google Drive API page on my appspot domain. I am unable to do it.

I am confused on how to create the key for the web application. What should be filled in the "Web origin" and what should be filled in "redirect_url".

If i put "http://www.my-domain-name.appspot.com" in both the fields to generate the key. It gives a redirect_url mismatch error.

The redirect_url created in the older google api website is different because it creates a redirect_url of "my-domain-name.appspot.com/ouath2callback"(I haven't put www as i don't have enough reputation :p). i am confused on what to be put in the respective fields while creating the key.
Please Help.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

You need to have "http://www.my-domain-name.appspot.com" registered as a redirect URI on [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

Comment: I have already registered my application on google api cloud console.